# Unable to login in android app using php and mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have created a android login page in eclipse.And using php code through wamp server i connected mysql database to the page. But while running the php file,i get errors as

1) Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\log\login.php on line 6

2) Notice: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\log\login.php on line 8

3) Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\log\login.php on line 10

4)Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\log\login.php on line 12

5)Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\log\login.php on line 13

6)No database selected

and also in the emulator i get stopped after "validating the user".Please help me.
NOTE: My username and password for mysql is 'root' and 'admin'
Screen1.java

```
package com.example.library;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Screen1 extends Activity {
    Button b;
    EditText et,pass;
    TextView tv;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen1);

        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);  
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameET);
        pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordET);
       // tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Screen1.this, "", 
                        "Validating user...", true);
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            login();                          
                        }
                      }).start();               
            }
        });
    }

    void login(){
        try{            

            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://localhost/log/login.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Screen1.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                startActivity(new Intent(Screen1.this, Screen2.class));
            }else{
                showAlert();                
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void showAlert(){
        Screen1.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Screen1.this);
                builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
                builder.setMessage("User not Found.")  
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           }
                       });                     
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();               
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_screen1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/index"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.library.Screen1" >

     <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
              android:textColor="#ffffffff"
              android:text="Please signin"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

           <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
              android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
              android:textColor="#ffffffff"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
              android:text="Rollno:"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/usernameET"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
              android:textColor="#ffffffff"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
              android:hint="eg:201103005" >
              <requestFocus />
      </EditText>
      <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView3"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#ffffffff"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
              android:text="Password:"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/passwordET"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usernameET"
              android:layout_alignRight="@+id/usernameET"
              android:hint="*******"
              android:textColor="#ffffffff"
              android:inputType="textPassword" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@+id/passwordET"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
               android:background="@drawable/sign_in_button"
               android:onClick="jumpscreen2"/>


</RelativeLayout
```

php code

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="mydatabase";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="admin";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query_search = "select * from tbl_user where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;
 if($rows == 0) { 
 echo "No Such User Found"; 
 }
 else  {
    echo "User Found"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Check your username or password or database in your mySql database, or try to connect it manually without using app. try using browser, if you able to connect using browser then use in Android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\log\login.php on line 6` tells you that you're using wrong credentials to connect to your MySQL database and/or your hostname isn't accessible.

- If you are on your desktop with WAMP installed, try "root" as username and a blank password ("").
- If you are on your Android device, you will have to make sure it can connect to your database (it may not be possible if you use `localhost` as hostname).

Comment: yea..i tried that..but then i got 2 errors  Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\log\login.php on line 12   and  Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\log\login.php on line 13

Comment: So problem solved. :) This is an other problem. POST is just empty. I guess no form was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use correct `username` and `password` for your database host,
later just try this code. That should work.

If you are using `wamp` for windows, your password will be just `""` (No password)

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="mydatabase";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query = "select * from tbl_user where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";

$result = @mysql_query($query);

if(!$result){
    die('ERROR: '.mysql_error());
}

else{

if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    echo "User found \n";
}

else{
    echo "not found";
}


} 

?>
```

For android, if you want to connect it to localhost,

change this line of code on your java class

`httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:80/log/login.php"); // make sure the url is correct.`

Comment: yea..i tried that change of username and password..but then i got 2 errors  Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\log\login.php on line 12   and  Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\log\login.php on line 13     and also in the emulator after i click signin,i went like "unfortunately,the app has stopped"

Comment: You got this Notices on the Android side or in your browser?

Comment: i got the error on the wamp server when i ran the php file

Comment: you should be running this on your app, not on your computer/mobile browser.

Comment: yeah.I ran the app in the emulator.And the app has stopped working